# Trello API: what are actions?

Tags: trello

I am going through Trello API docs. I am new to trello. I am trying to understand, what is below API going to give me?

GET /1/actions/[idAction]

what are these actions?
how are actions and cards associated as in what is the relationship between them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trello actions are basic action associated almost with all Trello entities. Trello action could be for example `addAttachmentToCard` which provides you information that attachment was added to card, this action is generated immediately when you add some attachment to card.

Action is defined as:

```
id
idMemberCreator
data
type
date
```

If you want get all actions of specific card you are able to use `GET /1/cards/[card id or shortlink]`. The relationship between Action and another Trello entity is N to one - Trello entity could have N actions but specific action (**is defined by ID!**) is associated only with one entity.

Comment: Also, actions can be found on member and board routes in addition to cards.